# MySQL SUM(BIGINT) query returns bytearray instead of BIGINT, but only when called as a prepared statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, prepared-statement, mysql-connector-python

I have the following MySQL query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(billable_size),
           SUM(billable_size),
           MIN(billable_size),
           MAX(billable_size)
      FROM inv_files
     WHERE billable_size >= %s
       AND billable_size < %s
```

The `billable_size` column is a `BIGINT`, and the `SUM()` of its values can get anywhere up to about 1e+14.

When I run this query using simple string interpolation --

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(query_sql % (from_size, to_size))
```

-- MySQL Connector/Python correctly returns the sum value as a Python `Decimal`.

But when I try to run it as a prepared statement --

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
cursor.execute(query_sql, (from_size, to_size))
```

-- the sum instead gets returned as a `bytearray`, causing any number of headaches. (Apparently there are some known issues with MySQL [returning byte arrays when it should return something else](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27551)? Maybe I should count myself lucky it works with plain string interpolation.)

Is there a SQL "type hint" or some other way I can get MySQL Connector/Python to correctly return the right type?